# Wrong value for dropdown attribute in Magento list.phtml

Tags: php, magento, attributes, dropdown

I created a custom attribute (dropdown) "product_overlay" in Magento (with options like "NEW", "Backorder", "Cashback available", etc.). I want to use the selected option in list.phtml to add a image to the view in case something is selected.

However, in some cases the system returns the option with the lowest ID (the one I created first) despite a different option or noting is selected. In other cases it works just fine.

I'm, using this line to get the selected value.

```
$overlay = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_overlay')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

What would be the right way to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For dropdown attributes, using getAttributeText() tends to be the more robust way of retrieving data:

```
$overlay = $_product->getAttributeText('product_overlay');
```

EDIT - you can then cycle through the potential options:

```
<?php
    if($overlay == "NEW") {
        echo "something";
    } elseif ($overlay == "Backorder") {
        echo "something else";
    } elseif ($overlay == "Cashback available") {
        echo "another something";
    } elseif {
        // etc
    }
?>
```

Comment: See my edit, are you filtering through the potential values / scenarios and echoing out what you want?

Comment: Well, I just started with echoing the retrieved values, and they were wrong.